# Extglob - Move all files not in a pattern but keep a specific one

Tags: bash, extglob

Let's say I have a folder named */folder1/* with the following files:

```
file.txt
log-2018-01-22.log
log-2018-01-21.log
log-2018-01-20.log
```

I want to move to `/folder2/` all files that aren't a `.log` with the current date, except `file.txt`. Since today is `2018-01-22` (in my timezone), I want to keep only `log-2018-01-22.log` and `file.txt` in `/folder1`.

The script that I'm using (seen below) doesn't keep `file.txt` in `/folder1/`, like I intend to, instead considering it as one of the files that aren't a `.log` with the current date and moving it to `/folder2/`.

```
shopt -s extglob
currentDate=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
mv /folder1/!(*$currentDate.log) /folder2/
```

Is there anything I can change in the `!($d.log)` part to make the command ignore `file.txt`?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
mv /folder1/!(log-$currentDate.log|file.txt) /folder2/
```

Comment: you wrote in your post: want to move to /folder2/ all files that aren't a .log with the current date, **except file.txt**

Comment: @JMCalil: Did you consider that I've inserted `log-`?

Comment: This worked for me: `mkdir testdir; cd testdir; touch file.txt log-2018-01-22.log log-2018-01-21.log log-2018-01-20.log; shopt -s extglob; echo !(log-$currentDate.log|file.txt)`. Output: `log-2018-01-20.log log-2018-01-21.log`